# Make wifi TX rate in menu bar instead of wifi icon

Tags: wifi, menu-bar

Is it possible to make the wifi icon in the menu bar the TX rate or the wifi speed rate? My wifi sometimes drops out and I would like to know if it is my wifi or the website I am visiting.

Answer (score 3):

While it won't display the TX rate permanently holding down the <kbd>option</kbd> key when you click on the WiFi pizza slice icon will display a great deal of information about your current WiFi connection, including the TX rate, RSSI (Received Signal Strength Indicator) and noise levels.

The RSSI and noise levels are more useful than the TX rate in determining the strength and health of your WiFi connection.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a pre-Sierra macOS, you can use [MenuMeters](https://www.ragingmenace.com/software/menumeters/). For Sierra and onwards, try Bjango's [iStatMenus](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/).

Disclosure: A happy consumer of both apps - no financial ties to Raging Menace or Bjango.com

Comment: FYI, there is also a [port of MenuMeters](https://member.ipmu.jp/yuji.tachikawa/MenuMetersElCapitan/) that works on Mac OS X 10.11 El Capitan, 10.12 Sierra, and 10.13 High Sierra.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [iStat Menus](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/). It is an advanced system monitor for in the menubar. It also monitors your network statistics.

> **Network**
>
> A realtime graph to keep on top of what’s being sent and received for all network connections, including a bandwidth breakdown
>   for the top 5 apps.